# Writing a heapsort in c with large input

Tags: c, random, heapsort

I have been trying to write a heapsort program, it currently works, however, whenever I give it over 500,000 items, the program crashes and windows pops up saying the program has stopped working, I am a little confused as to why, I have 32GB of RAM which should be plenty of space to run a heapsort.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void heapsort(int[],int);
void heapify(int[],int);
void adjust(int[],int);
int main() {
    int n=1000000,i,a[1000000];
    // printf("\nEnter the limit:");
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    int j=0;
    int num;
    while(fscanf(file, "%d", &num) > 0) {
        a[j] = num;
        j++;
    }
    fclose(file);
    heapsort(a,n);
    printf("\nThe Sorted Elements Are:\n");
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
      printf("\t%d",a[i]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
void heapsort(int a[],int n) {
    int i,t;
    heapify(a,n);
    for (i=n-1;i>0;i--) {
        t = a[0];
        a[0] = a[i];
        a[i] = t;
        adjust(a,i);
    }
}
void heapify(int a[],int n) {
    int k,i,j,item;
    for (k=1;k<n;k++) {
        item = a[k];
        i = k;
        j = (i-1)/2;
        while((i>0)&&(item>a[j])) {
            a[i] = a[j];
            i = j;
            j = (i-1)/2;
        }
        a[i] = item;
    }
}
void adjust(int a[],int n) {
    int i,j,item;
    j = 0;
    item = a[j];
    i = 2*j+1;
    while(i<=n-1) {
        if(i+1 <= n-1)
           if(a[i] <a[i+1])
            i++;
        if(item<a[i]) {
            a[j] = a[i];
            j = i;
            i = 2*j+1;
        } else
           break;
    }
    a[j] = item;
}
```

Comment: Can you elicit an actual error message? What did your debugger tell you about the problem?

Comment: Do you mean the program fails on every run when you make array `a` large enough for more than 500k items, or that it fails only when you actually provide an input that larger than 500k items?  If the former, then you are probably not giving your program a large enough stack (`a` is a local array variable in `main()`, and therefore allocated on the stack).

Comment: only when I provide it a number that large and let met copy the error message

Comment: To expand on John's comment, try declaring `int a[1000000]` as a global instead and see if that fixes it.  If that works, the problem was probably stack space.

Comment: `a.exe has stopped working windows is looking for a solution`

Comment: I have adjusting it to 1,000,000 I ended with the same message

Answer (score 1):

```
int main() {
  int n=1000000,i,a[1000000];
  // ...
```

> [..] it currently works, however, whenever I give it over 500,000 items, the program crashes [..]

You're holding *all* of your data on the stack, which is why I'm pretty sure that you're actually getting a *stack overflow*.

> [..] I have 32GB of RAM [..]

The amount of memory reserved for the stack is usually relatively small (IIRC around 8KB). The stack is intended to hold control information (like return addresses, in order to return from function calls) as well as what I'd call "data currently working with". There are ways to (try to) request more stack space, but in your case, that'd be an abuse of the stack.

In order to handle more (or better, an not previously known amount of) data you should use *heap* allocated memory. For that, you should look up some tutorial on the [use of `malloc` and `free`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory).

Another (*ugly*) solution would be to use static allocated memory:

```
int a[1000000]; // NOTE: Outside of any function, thus static global
int main() {
  // ...
```

Comment: I suspect you're right that it's a stack overflow, though the OP's response to my query would suggest otherwise.  Note, however, that if the stack were only 8kb then he wouldn't get more than a couple thousand elements before he overflowed it.  I believe the default stack size on Windows is 1MB.

Comment: well, the file with 1,000,000 is 9.5 MB

Comment: @JohnBollinger If I understood it correctly, then your/his adjustment only changed the array dimension, not its allocation. **Is it a global now or not?**

Comment: @DanielJour I don't know why you're tagging me on that.  I made no specific suggestion.  But yes, making the array global would be one reasonable way to get it off the stack.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I was referring to "your query" (and the OP's response). I'm pretty sure that this is a stack overflow. Thanks for the hint with the stack size on Windows. On my system (Linux 4.4.6 x86_64) it's 8KB.